# What is the name of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

**NOTE: I am trying to find the name of the specific LRU algorithm, not that this is a caching algorithm (I know it is, I wrote it).  Telling me this is a caching algorithm is like telling someone looking for the name red-black tree that it is a tree balancing algorithm.**

I recently created the following algorithm, but I am fairly certain someone must have done this before me and given it a name.  Does this look familiar to anyone?

Purpose: Keep a fixed size pool of strings and the number of times they have been seen.  If the pool exceeds the max size, only keep the most recently used items.

Pseudocode:

```
var cur
var old

func add_key(key)

    if cur not defined
        put a hash in cur

    if key in old
        copy value from old to cur for this key
        delete key from old

    increment cur[key]

    if there are too many keys in cur
        replace old with cur
        empty cur
        copy value from old to cur for this key
        delete key from old

    return cur[key]
```

A simple implementation in Perl 5 looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{ package Fixed::LRU::Counter;

    sub new {
        my ($class, $max) = @_;
        return bless {
            max => $max,
            cur => {},
            old => {},
        }, $class;
    }

    sub add_key {
        my ($self, $k) = @_;

        if ($self->{old}{$k}) {
            $self->{cur}{$k} = $self->{old}{$k};
            delete $self->{old}{$k};
        }

        $self->{cur}{$k}++;

        if (keys %{$self->{cur}} > $self->{max}) {
            $self->{old} = $self->{cur};
            $self->{cur} = { $k => $self->{old}{$k} };
            delete $self->{old}{$k};
        }

        return $self->{cur}{$k};
    }
}

my $c = Fixed::LRU::Counter->new(3);

for my $k (qw/a a b c d e f f g a f/) {
    print "$k: ", $c->add_key($k), "\n";
}
```

Comment: You're keeping track of the number of times an item is seen, but it doesn't appear to have any bearing on your caching algorithm (e.g.: it doesn't appear to be used at all to determine whether an item is evicted or not). Is this a red herring?

Comment: @mhum It is actually keeping track of how often we have seen the items (which is what we really care about), but there are possibly an infinite number of items, so we just want to keep track of the ones we have seen recently.

Comment: @Chas. Owens: While you may be using it somewhere else, I can't see how you're actually using it *within* your caching algorithm. For example, how would add_key() differ if you removed the line "$self->{cur}{$k}++"? While the return value of add_key() would then be meaningless, the contents of the cur and old buffers would remain the same, would they not? Or am I misunderstanding your implementation?

Comment: @mhum Yes, for caching purposes the increment could be replaced with a storing a 1.  In fact, you could probably reduce it to `return if key in curr; if key in old { move key to cur } else { add key to cur } replace old with cur and delete cur if there are too many keys in cur`.

Comment: Hmm, your bold intro implies that an answer like mine is unwanted. That's not really nice, as you did not add all this information in your initial question. How is one to know what you do and do not know about how it is called? You might want to be more specific beforehand, instead of adding remarks like that, if you don't want to be bothered by certain answers....

Comment: @Nanne I added the bold part because I got four answers like yours.  It isn't directed at you, it is direct at people who come to this question after you.  I have found that if I am not absolutely clear that first few people are going down a path that is not useful to me, all further answers will go down the same path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Least frequently used cache algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_Frequently_Used)

It is not LRU because LRU orders the cache items by last access time, not by access count like you do.

Comment: Good point that the class is LRU, not MRU, but I am looking for the name of the specific algorithm, not the general class.

Comment: @Chas The algorithm is so trivial that I don’t think it has an own name.

Comment: I think it is the simplest variant of LFU algorithm you can build. Most other algorithms based on LFU like LFU* or Window-LFU aim at solving the cache pollution inherent to this algorithm if no time is taken into account like in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this an implementation you could use for cache, or a pagefile?

It works with a most-recent method, there are ofcourse other strategies, like removing the least used, removing the newest, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly not MRU, but not exactly LRU either. Having both `cur` and `old` makes it look like you're trying to use `old` as an eviction buffer.

However, the way you're managing `cur` isn't really LRU *or* MRU -- when your cache gets full, you're keeping *only* the new entry, and throwing the *entire* rest of its content out to the eviction cache (`old`). Normally, when adding an entry would make your cache too large, you pick exactly *one* existing cache entry to throw out (to the eviction buffer, if you're using one). With the way you're throwing out the whole thing, I guess you could call it a "not most recently used cache with eviction buffer".

To be entirely honest, however, I think I'd *probably* use a much shorter, simpler name: "a mistake". I suppose there might be *some* circumstance under which this would/will/does work well, but at least right off it looks/sounds like a pretty poor idea.

The basic idea of a cache is that if something was used recently, it's probably going to be used again soon. In this case, however, you're (nearly) emptying the entire cache at almost completely arbitrary times. This *might* make sense if you know a *lot* about your data access, and know that you tend to load N data items and use them for quite a while, but when you load item N+1, you *probably* won't use the previous N items any more, so you might as well flush them all out, and recover them for the eviction buffer when that was wrong.